# Is there a Vim command to undo the last motion, e.g. <count>j or Ctrl-f?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

In Vim, if I issue a jump command, e.g. `G`, then I can put the cursor back where it was before the jump by using `Ctrl-o`.  However, `Ctrl-o` would not put my cursor back to the previous spot if I issued a movement command like `40j` or `Ctrl-f`, since they don't alter the jump list.  Is there a command which will undo movements such as those?

To be clear, I'm not looking for a "manual" answer, such as `40k` gets you back from `40j`, since such a command is not generically applicable in the way that `Ctrl-o` works.

Also, if no built-in command does this, then does any plugin do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override the default motions to provide for that, like this:

```
" j, k          Store relative line number jumps in the jumplist.
nnoremap <expr> k (v:count > 1 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'k'
nnoremap <expr> j (v:count > 1 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'j'
```

There's also the [reljump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4571), which implements the same.

However, be careful, because overdoing this will reduce the usefulness of the jump list. For that reason, I would advise against changing Ctrl-F / Ctrl-B.

Comment: For anyone interested in making these mappings work in IdeaVim, there is this issue in YouTrack that can be upvoted: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2750/How-to-add-numbered-movement-in-vim-to-ideas-jump-history

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a mark with `m'`, and then go back with ``` `` ```.

Comment: This solution requires the manual forethought to set the mark, though, which isn't applicable in the way that Ctrl-o works.